# Process of creating database on your own server

Tags: mysql, database, server

I bought "Hetzer" server so I can create my own database and practice a little bit. My server is using Ubuntu. I plan to also create a script (probably in node or asp) so my android application can communicate with database.

How to start with creating database, what to do?

Comment: i really don't know what a hetzer server is i know a compaan called hetzner, but still for practise, with ubuntu get a vm  and install what ever you want. it is free like oracle virtual box

Comment: Step one is finding out what DB servers work and are available on Ubuntu. "Hetzer" likely isn't very relevant here. Look for MySQL/MariaDB as starters, then add Apache and phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly https://www.hetzner.com/ is one of the best professional web hosting providers. In order to set up your Mysql server to your ubuntu machine. Install lamp stack. There are many tutorials about installing lamp. Then open your DB for remote connection or do kind of restful service to access your data in DB.